# How to set a default value if item not found while parsing the config

Tags: python-3.x

I am parsing a config.ini file using python ConfigParser, but if my config file does not have a specific item then there is an error. I want to have a check in place so that if i try to get a value which is not in the config file the that should return None.

Below is the config parser class that i have written.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

class MyConfiguration(object):
    def __init__(self, *file_names):
        # print(file_names)
        parser = ConfigParser()
        # parser.optionxform = str  
        found = parser.read(file_names)
        if not found:
            raise ValueError('No config file found!')
        for section in parser.sections():
            # print(section)
            # print(parser.items(section))
            self.__dict__.update(parser.items(section))
```

`config = MyConfiguration(FILE1, FILE2)`

to use any item from config file I am calling `config.key`

Expectation:
if I try to get `config.key_unknown` which is not available it should return `None`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting keys in the dictionary, you should probably use `__getattr__`:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

class MyConfiguration(object):
    def __init__(self, *file_names):
        # print(file_names)
        parser = ConfigParser()
        # parser.optionxform = str  
        found = parser.read(file_names)
        if not found:
            raise ValueError('No config file found!')
        self._parser = parser

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        for section in self._parser.sections():
            if key in section:
                return section[key]
        return None
```

Comment: and  how to get the values using the class object?

Comment: because if i still try config._parser.get("attributes", "key_unknown") it still throws error configparser.NoOptionError: No option 'key_unknown' in section: 'attributes

Comment: @Arun Just do `config.key_unknown`.

Comment: its returning None even for keys present in config file

Comment: @Arun Ah. That's surprising, actually. This is case-sensitive, I think; have you checked that?

Comment: I have commented out parser.optionxform = str which makes the options to be in lower cases. its not working

Comment: @Arun Are you definitely doing the keys, and not the groups?